# Update data in current row when only one column value changes in that row using trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have this users table in which I have many columns and what I want to do is to fire the trigger only when one of the column value changes and not the whole row.

```
USE [TempInvestManage]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[DailyEarning2]    Script Date: 9/13/2020 4:32:21 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[DailyEarning2] ON [dbo].[Users]
after update
as        
    DECLARE @UId INT
    declare @AdCount INT

    SELECT @UId = inserted.ID, @AdCount = inserted.AdCount     
    FROM INSERTED;

    with firstCte(Name,UID,PName,AdCount,ClickRate,ReferComission)
    as
    (
        select distinct Users.Name, Users.ID, Packages.PName, Users.AdCount, Packages.ClickRate, Packages.ReferCommission
        from Users
        inner join UserPackages on UserPackages.U_ID = Users.ID
        inner join Packages on Packages.PID = UserPackages.P_ID
        where U_ID = @UId and UserPackages.PackageStatus = 'true' 
    )
    update Users set DailyEarning = ClickRate * @AdCount
    from firstCte
    where ID = @UId and @AdCount != 0;

    update Users set TotalDailyEarning = TotalDailyEarning+DailyEarning, DailyEarning=0
    where ID = @UId and AdCount = 0;
```

[image: Table picture]

You can ignore joins for now. I only need someway to check if the `adCount` column changed when this trigger was fired and only then do I need to update the table. Otherwise I want this trigger to do nothing.

Comment: Your trigger has a serious problem: it assumes all updates will only ever affect one row.

Comment: can you please elaborate a little as someone else also told me this thing will fail for batch updates but i am not gonna do batch updates.can you please tell me the issue with an eg?

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-abusing-triggers

Comment: @AaronBertrand still didn't get it after reading from the link...do you mean if more then one person hits my database at the same time and do some update on the row in the same table then i will get incorrect results?please show a small test case where this trigger will fail

Comment: With the trigger you have in place, write an update statement that would affect two different users (e.g. `UPDATE dbo.Users SET AdCount += 1 WHERE ID IN (1,2);`) and see if the trigger updates the data for both of them. (The answer will be no.)

Comment: @AaronBertrand yes with above query only 1st Id row is updating  will this depict the same behavior like i said above two users accessing and updating their record at the same time?

Comment: If two users try to update the same row at the same time, one will win, and the other will be a lost update. That's not the problem I'm talking about here. Refresh the link and read the section "Not preparing for multi-row updates" - I updated the example to be more relevant to your scenario (without any of the ad count logic of course).

Comment: I'm not going to address your logic problem because it's late here but you absolutely must stop using `SELECT @variable = column FROM inserted;` - this fails silently if `inserted` contains more than one row.

Comment: @AaronBertrand for my project i am not worried about two people accessing same row at same time as it won't be the case only one user will be accessing his/her row but still with above query only one row gets updated and that's the first one

Comment: One more time, this isn’t about two different people updating one row at the same time, it’s about writing safe code and extends beyond the scope of this single project, but I give up. Good luck.

Comment: And if you can avoid using images to display data - formatted text is much better.

Answer (score 1):

This, I believe, is a trigger which implements your desired logic *and* works properly. Points to note:

1. No need for a CTE, just update the source table directly.
2. Combine all updates into a single update using `CASE` expressions.
3. Use `Inserted` in a set based fashion to ensure you handle multi-row updates. In this case `WHERE U.ID IN (SELECT ID FROM Inserted)` does the job.
4. Alias your tables to make your query more concise and readable.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[DailyEarning2] ON [dbo].[Users]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF UPDATE(AdCount)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE U set
            DailyEarning = CASE WHEN AdCount != 0 THEN ClickRate * AdCount ELSE 0 END
            , TotalDailyEarning = TotalDailyEarning + CASE WHEN AdCount = 0 THEN DailyEarning ELSE 0 END
        FROM Users U
        INNER JOIN UserPackages UP on UP.U_ID = U.ID
        INNER JOIN Packages P on P.PID = UP.P_ID
        WHERE U.ID IN (SELECT ID FROM Inserted)
        AND UserPackages.PackageStatus = 'true';
    END;
END;
```

Note: You need to double check that my logic matches your requirements.

Comment: will this work for multiple rows updates?btw its not working correctly..i just need to add dailyEarning value to TotalDailyEarning and set dailyEarning to 0 as soon as adCount column value changes to 0 if not then simply do dailyEarning= ClickRate*AdCount

Comment: This `WHERE U.ID IN (SELECT ID FROM Inserted)` line ensures you handle all the rows of `Inserted`.

Comment: @Jazz and note that a CTE isn't required.

Comment: can you please share any helpful link or eg for  case when subquery is returning more then one rows how to handle that code as update also fails in that scenario.plus what if try to update more then one tables?cte doesn't allow it

Comment: @Jazz ask a new question and provide a [mre] i.e. sample data, expected results, and query which causes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Dale K you got it working for multiple rows here's the working code tested for multiple updates

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[DailyEarningTest] ON [dbo].[Users]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF UPDATE(AdCount)
    BEGIN
        WITH firstCte([Name], ID, PName, AdCount, ClickRate, ReferComission, DailyEarning, TotalDailyEarning)
        AS (
            SELECT U.[Name], U.ID, P.PName, U.AdCount, P.ClickRate, P.ReferCommission, U.DailyEarning, U.TotalDailyEarning
            FROM Users U
            INNER JOIN UserPackages UP on UP.U_ID = U.ID
            INNER JOIN Packages P on P.PID = UP.P_ID
            WHERE U.ID IN (SELECT ID FROM Inserted)
            AND PackageStatus = 'true'
        )
        UPDATE firstCte SET
            DailyEarning =
            CASE WHEN AdCount != 0 THEN ClickRate * AdCount ELSE 0 END,
            TotalDailyEarning=TotalDailyEarning+
            CASE WHEN AdCount = 0 
            THEN DailyEarning ELSE 0  END 
        ;
    END;
END;
```

EDIT:-
as said by @Dale K cte is really not required

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[DailyEarningTest] ON [dbo].[Users]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF UPDATE(AdCount)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE U set
            DailyEarning = CASE WHEN AdCount != 0 THEN ClickRate * AdCount ELSE 0 END
            , TotalDailyEarning = TotalDailyEarning + CASE WHEN AdCount = 0 THEN U.DailyEarning ELSE 0 END
        FROM Users U
        INNER JOIN UserPackages UP on UP.U_ID = U.ID
        INNER JOIN Packages P on P.PID = UP.P_ID
        WHERE U.ID IN (SELECT ID FROM Inserted)
        AND PackageStatus = 'true';
    END;
END;
```